# Appending to an Object to an Array While Respecting its ordering

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an Array of Objects, and I wanted to keep its category ordering while appending the respecting its descending ordering.

```js
function magicFunction(data){
 let index = null;
  arr.map((val, i) => {
   if(val.name === data.name){
   if(val.size > data.size){
       index = i + 1;
     } 
     else if (val.size <= data.size){
       if((arr.length !== i -1) && arr[i + 1].size < data.size){
        index = i - 2;
       } else if ((arr.length !== i -1) && arr[i + 1].size > data.size ){
        index = i;
       }
      }
     }
   });
  if(index === null){
   arr.push(data);
  } else {
   arr.splice(index, 0, data);
  }
  
}
const arr = []
magicFunction({name: 'CAT_1', size: 175});
magicFunction({name: 'CAT_5', size: 20});
magicFunction({name: 'CAT_1', size: 500});
magicFunction({name: 'CAT_6', size: 2});
magicFunction({name: 'CAT_1', size: 5000});
console.log(arr);
```

- However the last Obj I append does not honor the descending order?
- The correct order is the last one added should be the first element.
- so arr[0] should === {name: 'CAT_1', size: 5000}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include your desired output please? And best if you can put your code inside a HTML snippet here in SO so that we can run it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making assumptions about what you want the output to look like:

```js
function magicFunction(data){
  arr.push(data);
  
  arr.sort((a,b) => {
    const nameNumA = parseInt(a.name.split('_')[1]);
    const nameNumB = parseInt(b.name.split('_')[1]);    
    if (nameNumA == nameNumB){
      return b.size - a.size
    } else{
      return nameNumA - nameNumB;
    } 
  });
  
  return void(0);
  
}
const arr = []
magicFunction({name: 'CAT_1', size: 175});
magicFunction({name: 'CAT_5', size: 700});
magicFunction({name: 'CAT_5', size: 20});
magicFunction({name: 'CAT_1', size: 500});
magicFunction({name: 'CAT_1', size: 5000});
magicFunction({name: 'CAT_6', size: 2});
magicFunction({name: 'CAT_6', size: 200});
console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "CAT_1",
    "size": 5000
  },
  {
    "name": "CAT_1",
    "size": 500
  },
  {
    "name": "CAT_1",
    "size": 175
  },
  {
    "name": "CAT_5",
    "size": 700
  },
  {
    "name": "CAT_5",
    "size": 20
  },
  {
    "name": "CAT_6",
    "size": 200
  },
  {
    "name": "CAT_6",
    "size": 2
  }
]
```

**Of course, performance-wise it is better to add each item then sort once and not sort each time you call the function but since I want to stick to the way you are calling the function, I need to sort each time.**

**Additionally, it's not good practice to mutate an array outside of the function closure, i.e. in the global scope.**

So, that said, I would solve it like this:

```js
const arr = []
arr.push({name: 'CAT_1', size: 175});
arr.push({name: 'CAT_5', size: 700});
arr.push({name: 'CAT_5', size: 20});
arr.push({name: 'CAT_1', size: 500});
arr.push({name: 'CAT_1', size: 5000});
arr.push({name: 'CAT_6', size: 2});
arr.push({name: 'CAT_6', size: 200});
const sortedArr = arr.sort((a,b) => {
    const nameNumA = parseInt(a.name.split('_')[1]);
    const nameNumB = parseInt(b.name.split('_')[1]);    
    if (nameNumA == nameNumB){
      return b.size - a.size
    } else{
      return nameNumA - nameNumB;
    } 
  });
console.log(sortedArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I believe this would just sort by size correct? I was using splice, since these names ordered in a specific way. I'm doing some canvas drawing, and if I overlay everything on size alone, certain layers of the canvas are not visible.

Comment: So you want to also sort on ‘Cat_n’? i.e sort ‘cat_1’ as a “group” sorted on size then ‘cat_2’ as a group sorted on size etc?

Comment: Perfect. Great to hear!